# Create datatable using jquery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to process `aaData` to create data table. but i get error DataTables warning:

`table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. table id is correct.1`

```
{
   "jsondata":{
      "draw":1,
      "iTotalRecords":100,
      "iTotalDisplayRecords":100,
      "aaData":[
         {
            "email":"admin@admin.com",
            "name":"adminsamju",
            "total_assignmets":24,
            "total_judges":2,
            "progress":8.333333333333332
         },
         {
            "email":"samjad20@gmail.com",
            "name":"samjad2",
            "total_assignmets":12,
            "total_judges":2,
            "progress":16.666666666666664
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Jquery code is here

```
$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'{{ route("admin.progresses.index") }}?season='+season+'&score_set='+score_set+'&p='+id,
         success:function(data) {
           $(".progress-table tbody").remove()
                $('.progress-table').DataTable({
                "searching": true, //this is disabled because I have a custom search.
                "aaData": [data['jsondata']['aaData']], //here we get the array data from the ajax call.
                "aoColumns": [
                   { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                   { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
                   { data: 'progress', name: 'progress' },
                   { data: 'total_judges', name: 'total_judges' },
                   { data: 'total_assignmets', name: 'total_assignmets' }
                ]
            });
       }

});
```

Comment: there is not such `attribute` called `aaData` and `aoColumns` on datatable library (from https://datatables.net) attributes called `data` and `columns` check the link https://datatables.net/manual/data/

Comment: yes i changed  still i get same error

Comment: You are trying to re-initialize the datatable which is already created once. Please use `destroy: true` option inside your `$('.progress-table').DataTable()`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to re-initialize the datatable which is already created once. Please use `destroy: true` option inside your `$('.progress-table').DataTable()` Please check [this link](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) for more details on `destroy`

```
$(".progress-table tbody").remove()
    $('.progress-table').DataTable({
    "destroy": true, //used to destroy the original datatable and re-initialize
    "searching": true, //this is disabled because I have a custom search.
    "aaData": [data['jsondata']['aaData']], //here we get the array data from the ajax call.
    "aoColumns": [
       { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
       { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
       { data: 'progress', name: 'progress' },
       { data: 'total_judges', name: 'total_judges' },
       { data: 'total_assignmets', name: 'total_assignmets' }
    ]
});
```